# What order should my Javascript be in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I recently transfered over my files from one server to another. For some reason on the new
server I am getting odd errors in chrome under the network tab such as: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: autoResize is not defined

Some pages even stopped working!
I was messing around with the order of my script links.
Here is my current order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/responsive-tables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/custom.js"></script>
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-manager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tools.js"></script>
<script src='https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

How should I order this and is there any way to make it so the order doesnt matter?
Thanks I have no idea what to search for this so I am stuck.

EDIT: New order. Less errors. http://prntscr.com/3y98gt

```
<!---JQuery/Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/responsive-tables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/assetsz/js/custom.js"></script>
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page-manager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tools.js"></script>
<script src='https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: put `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` first

Comment: js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js should be just after assets/assetsz/js/modernizr.min.js

Comment: You have to put the files in dependency order. E.g. all jQuery plugins depend on jQuery, so jQuery should be included before them. Files that don't have dependencies on each other can be put in any order.

Comment: Basicly modernizr, jquery, jquery.migrate, jquery.ui, bootstrap, the rest.

Comment: i'm disturbed with the stupidity of your question, especially since your website is taking payments through coinbase.

Comment: Su4p and Karl-Johan Sjögren are contradicting.

Comment: Less errors now. http://prntscr.com/3y93sv Why is coinbase bad? It works great.

Comment: @user3728587 You don't seem to have comprehension skills. r3wt is saying that it is shame on you to ask such question and be paid for programming it.

Comment: @sawa Im not a developer, I am a user fixing work that my developer didnt fix.

Comment: i didn't say coinbase was bad, but since you mentioned it they had a flaw in their api THAT THEY REFUSED TO FIX allowing the hacker Shubham Sham to compile a list of 1300 emails and the full name of the person the email belonged to. let's just say they are *frugal*. they refused to pay the guy who found the flaw, so he exposed them.

Comment: Well that sucks, I dont care if my email and name are out there though. Only bad part is, what if there is more exploits? :(

Answer (score 2):

- 1rst place: JQuery
- 2nd place: JQuery Migrate
- 3rd place: JQuery UI
- 4th place: Bootstrap

Order of the rests are less important, but pay attention to don't call function before is loading by the `script` tag, eso

Another advice: separate CSS and JS files. It's a bad idea to mix everything.

Pay also attention: for performance reason, it's better to load JS at the end of the page. But CSS have to take place in the `head` section.

Comment: Don't forget that he has `jquery.migrate` in there as well, it should at least be after bootstrap put preferably just after jquery.

Comment: Hmm. Starting it tick me off a little because I still cannot find the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, every script which uses jQuery should be loaded after your jQuery include. So, putting jquery-1.11.1.min.js on top should be a quick fix.

Comment: placing it after modernizr would be optimal.